# Pin inductance vs pin capacitance in determining rise and fall times

Tags: capacitance, inductance, vlsi, timing-analysis

I am a beginner in digital electronics and VLSI.

I know that pin capacitance is an important parameter in determining the rise and fall times of logic gates and ICs.

This is supported by my intuition since, capacitance does not allow the voltage to rise and fall instantaneously. Since the rise and fall times of these logic ICs are finite, there should be some inherent input and output capacitance respectively.

Another parameter which introduces delay is inductance. It does not allow the current to instantaneously reach final values (since voltage is proportional to current by Ohm's law, so current should also have a rise and fall.) Due to finite delays, pin inductance should also be present in the logic ICs.

Pin capacitance is given a lot of importance while pin inductance is hardly talked about.

1. Does pin inductance exist?
2. Is it very small, to be neglected?
3. Is there any other reason to not talk of inductance completely? I haven't seen many reference of inductance in electronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it exists.
Usually it is small enough to be neglected.
Because it is small enough, it can usually be ignored.

Consider a representative logic IC. The wirebond inductance is about 1 nH/mm of wire, so consider 5 mm ==> 5 nH. The pin capacitance may be about 2 pF. This gives an L.C resonance of about 1.6 GHz, or a rise time of 100 ps. If you are operating at edge rates much slower than that, the system basically just looks like the capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Does pin inductance exist?
```

Yes, primarily in the IC bonding between die and package. The bigger the package compared to the actual die, the bigger the inductance. This is a reason why BGA is advantageous in high-frequency/high-speed designs.

```
2. Is it very small, to be neglected?
```

Depends on the use-case. In common digital design (following most "rules of thump"): Yes.

**BUT:** The rich decoupling seen on FPGAs/SOCs is primarily motivated by lead-inductance. The capacitors "turn" the impedance more to the "real axis" and therefore aid in preventing voltage glitches on current spikes.

```
3. Is there any other reason to not talk of inductance completely? I haven't seen many reference of inductance in electronics.
```

Don't create issues if there are none. That is the basic mind-set in engineering. Only if there are problems: solve them.

If pin-inductance can cause problems (and it certainly can), the application is either very specialized or high-end.

[Intel Talk on IC-Packages](https://cmosedu.com/jbaker/projects/packaging/Performance%20Characteristics%20of%20Packages.pdf)

[ResearchGate on Trends in IC-Packages](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228653658_Trends_in_assembling_of_advanced_IC_packages/download)

[TI App-Note on Package characteristics](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa405a/snoa405a.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a phenomenon called "ground bounce" that depends heavily on pin inductance. Basically ground bounce is about voltage drops on pins and bond wires caused by fast changing currents. These voltage drops can cause voltage differences between Die-GND and PCB-GND that can lead to all sorts of problems.

If you are doing a little research on "ground bounce" you'll find a lot of information on pin inductance.